# CSS Typing Effect not spanning multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I have had a look around this site and can't seem to find a fix for this issue.

I have this typing effect that scrolls through various sentences in an array, I need it to wrap onto a second line whenever it reaches a certain width but if I remove the `white-space: wrap` you can see all of the text just on multiple lines and it expands the width slowly, I need it to only wrap after a certain width is reached.

I tried adding `white-space: wrap` at a certain point in the animation, however, this doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

Code here:

```css
.type-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  color: var(--white);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 28%;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 29px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 36%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: typing 5s steps(100, end) infinite;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#cursor {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 3px;
  height: 34px;
  background: var(--white);
  animation: blink 1s steps(100, end) infinite;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
@keyframes typing {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    background: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    background: var(--white);
  }
}
```

```html
<div className="type-container">
  <div className="content">
    <h1 className="heading-1">
      Our Management Team has over 50 years of experience:
    </h1>
    <div className="typed-section">
      <ul className="heading-2">
        <li id="typed-word">
          {sentence}
          <div id="cursor" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to go with typed.js https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

Comment: Will this work with React?

Comment: To get a proper typing effect I think you'll have to introduce some Javascript. Also, what do you want it to look like if the sentence is too long for the 100px height which has been allowed?